# Z-index issue with Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, fullpage.js, particles.js

I am using a fullPage.js Plugin which converts each section into a full page slide show based website and vertically centers the content.

I am also using ParticlesJS to achieve some animation effect in the background - which generated a Canvas to achieve the animation which seems to take up a higher `z-index`

Event thought i am trying to assign a z-index lower to the `canvas` and higher one to the `content` i am not able to select the text and access the form.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

[Website](http://play.mink7.com/creo/)

Comment: You just had to set the parent (`#hero-unit`) `z-index` to 1 and canvas' one to -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply the css pointer-event

add this `pointer-events: none` to your `particles-js-canvas-el` and you should be able to click your inputs

Comment: you are my hero :) thanks a lot. i learnt a new property today ;)

Comment: Don't worry about it mate :)

Comment: unfortunately it wasn't implemented before IE11 http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events